# How do I call a function handle from cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, anonymous-function

What I try to do is keep a cell-array of function handles, and then call one of them in a loop. It doesn't work, and it seems to me that what I get is just a 1x1 cell array, and not the function handle within it.

I am not fixed on using cell arrays, so if another collection works it's fine by me.

This is my code:

```
func_array = {@(x) x, @(x) 2*x }
a = func_array(1) %%% a = @(x) x
a(2) %%% (error-red) Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
a(0.2) %%% (error-red) Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
logicals.
```

Thank you
Amir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
a = func_array(1)
```

you need to access the content of the cell array, not the element.

```
a = func_array{1}
```

and everything works fine. The visual output in the command window looks the same, which is truly a little misleading, but have a look in the workspace to see the difference.

As mentioned by **chappjc** in the comments, the intermediate variable is not necessary. You could call your functions as follows:

```
func_array{2}(4)    %// 2*4

ans =  8
```

---

Explanation of errors:

```
a(2) %%% (error-red) Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

`a` is still a cell array, but just with one element, therefore `a(2)` is out of range.

```
a(0.2) %%% (error red) Subscript indices must either be real positive ...
```

... and arrays can't be indexed with decimals. But that wasn't your intention anyway ;)

Comment: This. +1 You can also run the function directly with cascaded indexing like `func_array{1}(0.2)`.